# USB tethered connection via Nexus One not showing on NetworkManager

Tags: 10.10, networking, usb, android

When plugging my Nexus One (Android 2.3.3) via USB and activating the "USB Tethering" option, I cannot enable the connection via Network Manager, because I just see a gray "Disconnected" option.

If I connect manually (`dhclient usb0`, add nameserver to `/etc/resolv.conf`) it works.

How can I make it work with Network Manager? I use Ubuntu 10.10.

Comment: I also wasn't getting a connection after I clicked on "usb tethering".  It took a while to realize (doh!) that I also needed to hit "done" on the android to have the change of setting take place.  Then network manager just automatically connected via usb0.  This was on ubuntu 11.04, natty.  I note for the record that it is using the rndis_host driver.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It seems to be a problem with the Ubuntu kernel 2.6.35. I have installed the 2.6.36 and 38 kernels from Ubuntu mainline kernel PPA and then there is no problem, thing is I would like to use this kernel since the wireless backport drivers seem to give me less issues. I may have to boot the kernel for the application, 2.6.38 if I'm on the road and 2.6.35 if I'm in the office. Hope this helps you though:

http://kernel.ubuntu.com/~kernel-ppa/mainline/

Download and install the version you want, Google "mainline kernel howto" if you are struggling.

Comment: I'm going to wait that a newer kernel makes its way through the official upgrades. Thanks for the pointer!